# Flask blueprint as a package | setuptools

Tags: python, flask, setuptools

I have a flask blueprint that I'm pushing to GitHub as a separate repo. Then I install it via

*pip install git@httpps://....*

I get the package in my venv and it's all good I can import code etc.

**However** there is an issue. I don't see HTML/CSS/js files that are visible on GitHub.

I found similar errors on here but the solutions that I tested don't work. Maybe there is an error in my folder structure (if so how to do it correctly? flask needs to see them too) maybe it's something different.

Here is my folder structure all of the folders have **init**.py

```
src
   updater
      SWupdater
      templates
        static
           js
             *.js
           css
             external_css
                  *.css
             *.css
           images
            *.jpg 
        SWupdater
            *.html
```

This is my setup without names/descriptions etc

```
setuptools.setup(
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='src', exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*"]),
    package_dir={"updater": "src/updater"},
    zip_safe=False,
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[],
    classifiers=[],
    python_requires='>=3.7'
)
```

What I've tried to do in my setup.py

-added package_data

```
package_data={"updater/SWupdater/templates": ["SWUpdater/*"],
               "updater/SWupdater/templates/static":["css/*", "images/*", "js/*"]},
```

-added include_package_data

```
include_package_data=True,
```

-a combination of package_data/include
-line order combination (one higher one lower)

I do not build this package, I only push it to GitHub and install it into my venv

Comment: `package_dir` in `setup.py` seems incorrect to me. It should probably be `package_dir={'': 'src'},`. -- For the rest: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for answers.

- you don't need package_data in setup.py
- you need manifest.in

In my case I've created manifest with this line

```
recursive-include src\updater\SWupdater\templates\* .
```

to include all html/css/js files